# How to *prevent* magit-status from opening in full window

Tags: emacs, magit

Since I upgraded magit, executing magit-status replaces my patiently crafted window arrangement with a single, huge window. Ok, when quit magit it restores the frame layout. However, I never quit magit. I much prefer the old behavior, where magit-status stayed in the windows in which I ran it. Can I get the old behavior back?

Comment: Upgraded from which version to which version?

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2194/115 The linked emacs StackExchange question shows the use of `display-buffer-alist` for controlling any emacs window. Have a look at the linked documentation in that solution for more info.

Comment: Flagged for deletion because op did not follow up and so this also won't help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

There was no such change it Magit itself.

Are you using some "starter kit"? If so you should probably check there first.